# what should I put in the .htaccess file to deploy my site on hostinger?

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, hosting

I'm deploying my first project on Hostinger. It's a React app created according to the basic config given on reactjs.org. I have uploaded my entire folder to the server via FileZilla and am now trying to configure my .htaccess file but I am only getting 500 errors back. I put this file in my folder called react-portfolio but nothing works. The whole project is stored in the react-porfolio folder.

here is what I tested first

```
DirectoryIndex /react-portfolio/public/index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ react-portfolio/public/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

here is the second file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Comment: _"but I am only getting 500 errors back"_ - then go check the log files, to find out what the _cause_ of those errors actually was.

Comment: What exactly do you want this code to do? What is your directory structure?